# How do I resolve WebDriver Exception: Message: Timeouts

Tags: robotframework

I keep getting WebDriver Exception: Message: Timeouts everytime I run my script. I have python version 2.7.14, robotframework version 3.0.4, and selenium library version 3.1.1. I hope someone can help me.

Below is the code that I am working on.

```
*** Keywords ***
Go to Google
    Open Browser  https://google.com  Firefox
    Maximize Browser Window
```

Below are the logs that I got.

```
05:40:32.935    INFO    Opening browser 'Firefox' to base url 'https://google.com'.     
05:40:39.772    FAIL    WebDriverException: Message: timeouts
```

Comment: Please add a code sample and the actual exception you're getting - your question is this form is too genaral and vague. And in general the SeleniumLibrary comes with plethora of keywords which will wait for the DOM/the page to change, and continue at ones it does; take a look at the [Wait Until ones](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Contains) in its documentation.

Comment: Go to Google
    Open Browser  https://google.com  Firefox
    Maximize Browser Window

Comment: I added the code above. It's just a very simple code which will just open google.

Comment: Please add the sample and the full exception inside your question (edit it) - the comments are not often checked for, and any formatting is lost.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on why the timeouts happen. If they happen because your website is slow, you need to either speed up the web server or increase the timeout.

Another reason could be that you are waiting for something that will never come. For example, you might have a typographical error in an id or xpath.

We can't give a specific answer since timeouts can happen for many reasons. You will need to look at the actual timeout message and the keyword that caused it, and figure out the root cause. Once you understand the root cause (typo, slow server, etc), you will probably be able to figure out the solution.

Comment: 05:40:32.935  INFO  Opening browser 'Firefox' to base url 'https://google.com'.  
05:40:39.772  FAIL  WebDriverException: Message: timeouts

Comment: *** Keywords ***
Go to Google
    Open Browser  https://google.com  Firefox
    Maximize Browser Window

Comment: I added the logs that I got and the code that I was working on. Even if I add a timeout to my code, it's not helping.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I downloaded the Chrome driver from https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/. Then I added this line to my code.

Create Webdriver  Chrome  executable_path=C:\Python27\chromedriver.exe

My keyword looks like the following now.

```
Go to Google 
    Create Webdriver  Chrome  executable_path=C:\\Python27\\chromedriver.exe
    Open Browser  https://google.com  Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
```

Answer (score 0):

1. install Firefox driver https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/.
2. add the driver to Environmental variableson your machine

[image]

[image]
3. You can now run your test

```
Go to Google 
    Open Browser  https://google.com  Firefox
    Maximize Browser Window
```